# Concurrency and messaging framework for Java ME

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me, messaging, actor

In Java, we could implement different "modules" which could be running in its own thread and could message other "modules" which are running in other threads. I could do this using [Mindroid](https://github.com/esrlabs/Mindroid.java), [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained) [Service](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ServiceExplained) and [EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) libraries, or Actor type frameworks like [Kilim](http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim/) or [Jetlang](http://code.google.com/p/jetlang/).

However, I need this to work for [Oracle Java Micro Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_me) 3.4 and possibly Java Micro Edition 8 as well. It will run on embedded systems (e.g. like on [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_pi) or even less powerful hardware), so it should be lightweight. The license should preferably be [free and permissive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_free_software_licence) (e.g. BSD, MIT, Apache 2.0). Also, it should specifically be in Java and not any other JVM languages (so [Akka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akka_%28toolkit%29) is out).

Please recommend a suitable library or framework based on these criteria.

Comment: If each service runs on its own thread, then using BockingQueue is enough. If you feel that it is not enough, then you has other requirements, which you did not tell about.

Comment: I've tried this before, but it would be nice to have a full-featured framework, should one be available.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggest [Mbassador](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador) as messaging framewrok to me. It's under MIT license and is a very light-weight message (event) bus implementation following the publish subscribe pattern. It is designed for ease of use and aims to be feature rich and extensible while preserving resource efficiency and performance.

Comment: Do you know if it's usable with Java ME?

Comment: I didn't test it with JavaME but I'm developing a system on embedded board with Java and I'm going to use Mbassador for message communication between system's module, if it can pass performance test.
I'll comment here if it was successful.